# how to compile tex file with -shell-escape in AucTeX using C-c C-c on ubuntu

Tags: emacs, auctex, shell-escape

I want to compile my tex file with `-shell-escape` option in Emacs + AucTex using `C-c C-c` key binding.

It gave me an error to run with -shell-escape. I know I can do it through terminal by `latex -shell-escape la.tex` but I want AucTeX to do it.

I even added a local varible `% TeX-command-extra-options: -shell-escape` but it gave the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put it into a `Local Variables` block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

When I open the file Emacs warns me:

```
The local variables list in test.tex
contains values that may not be safe (*).

Do you want to apply it?  You can type
y  -- to apply the local variables list.
n  -- to ignore the local variables list.
!  -- to apply the local variables list, and permanently mark these
      values (*) as safe (in the future, they will be set automatically.)

  * TeX-command-extra-options : "-shell-escape"
```

When I answer `y` and use the <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> shortcut, I see in the log

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``lualatex --jobname=test  -file-line-error -shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
```

Your output might differ slightly because I have changed some of Emacs' and AucTeX's default settings.

Comment: well. when I added the variable, the variable block entered automatically, but the warning didn't open. So I did `M-x revert-buffer` and warning came and every thing went smoothly. So thank you.